# How to get the total of every monday to saturday or tuesday to sunday in a month dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to get the the total of days in a month like for every monday to saturday or tuesday to sunday then multiply by working hours. It depends on the user if what they like to input in cell. However, the CALCULATION it depends on the date where the user input either in textbox or cell.

```vb
For X = 2 To lastRow 
    val = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(X, 2).Value 
    If UCase(val) Like "*TO*" Then 
        Dim numStringTo As Integer 
        Dim strToDays() As String 
        Dim wordToCount As Long 
        numStringTo = 3 
        strToDays = VBA.Split(val, " ") 
        wordToCount = UBound(strToDays) 
        whEveryDay =  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(X, 4).Value 
        whEveryDay = whEveryDay * Weekday(nb_days, 6) 
        Debug.Print "Every = " & whEveryDay 
    End If 
Next X
```

I need to get the total of days in a month and multiply by working hours. As of now we are in January 2023 and the pattern for January is **2-7,9-14,16-21,23-28,30-31** and the patter for November 2022 is **1-5,8-12,15-19,22-26,29-30**.

For example:

| Days | Date | Working Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| every Monday to Saturday | 2-7,9-14,16-21,23-28,30-31 | 1.2 |
| every Tuesday to Saturday | 1-5,8-12,15-19,22-26,29-30 | 0.5 |

Example of calculation:

**Days * Working hours**

And I need the calculation dynamically like for example if I change the cell of "every Monday to Saturday" to "every Wednesday to Monday" so, the count of days in a month will be also dynamically.

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: every Tuesday to Saturday 1-5,8-12,15-19,22-26,29-30 ? which month is this ?

Comment: Saying "As of now we are in January 2023", how "every Tuesday to Saturday" to return "1-5,8-12,15-19,22-26,29-30"? First `Tuesday` is on third of the month...

Comment: Ow sorry I didn't see that, for pattern "1-5,8-12,15-19,22-26,29-30" is under of the November 2022.

Comment: And how the necessary code/solution to know what month is it about?

Comment: @FaneDuru using text box because the user needs to input the month and date for example the user input a date 01/01/2023 but the date return in different format like this Jan-2023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, s As String, dt As Date
    s = InputBox("Input Date")
    If IsDate(s) Then
        dt = CDate(s)
    Else
        MsgBox s & " not a date", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            s = .Cells(r, "B").Value
            If UCase(s) Like "*TO*" Then
               ' total days in column E
               .Cells(r, "E") = mydatecalc(dt, s)
               ' hrs per day * days
               .Cells(r, "F").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox "Calc done for " & Format(dt, "mmm yyyy")
End Sub

Function mydatecalc(dtNow As Date, s As String) As Long

    Dim m As Integer, s1 As String, s2 As String, d As String
    Dim dt As Date, dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date
    Dim n As Integer, ar, bCount As Boolean, msg As String
         
    m = Month(dtNow) ' input month
    dtStart = DateSerial(Year(dtNow), m, 1)
    dtEnd = DateAdd("m", 1, dtStart) - 1
    
    ar = Split(s, " ")
    s1 = Left(ar(1), 3)
    s2 = Left(ar(3), 3)
    
    For dt = dtStart To dtEnd
        d = Format(dt, "ddd")
        If d = s1 Then bCount = True
        If bCount Then
            n = n + 1
            msg = msg & vbLf & n & " " & Format(dt, "ddd dd")
        End If
        If d = s2 Then bCount = False
    Next
    
    'MsgBox s & " = " & n & " days in " & Format(dtNow, "mmm yyyy") & msg
    mydatecalc = n
End Function
```

Comment: I need dynamically for example I have text box which text box because the user needs to input the date for example the user input a date 01/01/2023 but the date in text box return in different format like this "Jan-2023". So, the calculation is based on user input.

Comment: @James _user input a date 01/01/2023_ ? Where does the user Change input the date is it here `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(X, 4).Value` ? Change `dtNow = Date` to `dtNow = CDate("wherever the user inputs the date")`

Comment: Where should I place this code ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(X, 4).Value from your example?

Comment: You can't just set as static as monday to saturday or tuesday to sunday. This is another example what if the user input the date of January 2022 and the user wants to know the total of days multiply by working hours as stated to my problem.

Try to insert this example to a cell:

Date                                        Working Hours 
every Wednesday to Sunday  0.5

Try to compare it, this is example where the expected output will be Wednesday to Sunday.

Comment: @JamesFranco The static value is just to prove the code. In your code how is `val` value in `If UCase(val) Like "*TO*" Then`  set ?

Comment: Yeah that's a static because I used wild card to search all the rows in the input file if has a value of "*TO*". Anyways, I appreciate your help, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @JamesFranco The `"*TO*"` is a static string but I was referig to the `val` in `UCase(val)` which I assume is the variable holding the string like "Wednesday to Sunday"

Comment: this is my code:

For X = 2 To lastRow
 val = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(X, 2).Value
 If UCase(val) Like "*TO*" Then
    Dim numStringTo As Integer
    Dim strToDays() As String
    Dim wordToCount As Long
    
    numStringTo = 3
    
    strToDays = VBA.Split(val, " ")
    wordToCount = UBound(strToDays)
    whEveryDay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(X, 4).Value
    whEveryDay = whEveryDay * Weekday(nb_days, 6)
    Debug.Print "Every = " & whEveryDay
  End If
 Next X

Comment: Is there any chance to get the possible output?

Comment: Which columns do you want the output in ? Where is the month inout or it just the current Jan 2023 ?

Comment: Ah my code does compute every monday and saturday only, but I need the code who compute the total of days in a month from monday to saturday so it means the sunday will not compute only the monday, tuesday, wednesday, thurdays, friday and saturday until the end of month.

Comment: on the text box, here:

"I need dynamically for example I have text box where the user needs to input the date for example the user input a date format like this 01/01/2023 but the date in text box return in different format like this "Jan-2023" so it doesn't matter. So, the calculation is based on the user input."

Comment: No, not the literally month here's the exact example:

1st: Insert this pattern of any cell (every Monday to Saturday)
2nd: Insert this working hours (1.2) on the side of (every Monday to Saturday)

Now you have a data in your cell

3rd: We are in january 2023 now so if the user input a date like this 01/01/2023
4th: Once the user input the data then it automatically compute all days in January 2023 (monday, tuesday, wednesday, thurdays, friday and saturday until the end of month.)
5th: Once you get the total value of days in a month now multiply the days in working hours (days * wh)

Comment: continuation of the steps:

6th: once you already compute so the expected output replaces the text on the working hours cell.

Comment: the first you do or the code you was sent to this thread was correct but my point is you can't just do static you must have a user input then when a user input a date like 01/01/2023 it calculate all the possible days who given on the cell (every monday to saturday) then multiply by working hours

like this:

total days * working hours

Expected output was the working hours like 0.9 or 1.2 etc.

Comment: _Expected output was the working hours like 0.9 or 1.2 etc_ ? Your question was _how to get the the total of days in a month_. That is shown in column E and column F is the number of days * working hours.

Comment: NO, the output was the same january 2023 inside of the text box where all the data is in debug.print that it show the calculation of how many mondays do we have in January 2023

Comment: would you please remove the calculation for days in column F. I need a calculation for hours in column E. Again, the calculation is based on the user input inside of a "TEXT BOX" that match in a date.

Comment: Please don't make the situation complicated. As a I mention, I used TEXT BOX not a literal INPUT.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with a formula as well (Excel 365) and the following setting:

```
=LET(monthDays,SEQUENCE(EDATE(A2,1)-A2,1,A2),
weekdays,FILTER(SEQUENCE(1,7),B2:H2<>""),
workingHours,I2,
workedDays,FILTER(monthDays,ISNUMBER(MATCH(WEEKDAY(monthDays,2),weekdays,0))),
COUNT(workedDays)*workingHours)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I convert or code it in VBA? Because I used VBA code, excel is just my input file.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next solution. The range to be processed starts from column B:B and the return will be done in E:E. The code assumes that all strings in B:B contain the necessary data of pattern "every 'day name' to 'day name'":

```
Sub getHours()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, curDate As Date
   
   curDate = Date 'use here your date where from to extract the month
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   lastR = ws.Range("B" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = ws.Range("B2:E" & lastR).Value2
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 4) = TotalHoursPerDaysGroup(CStr(arr(i, 1)), curDate, CDbl(arr(i, 3)))
   Next i
   
   ws.Range("B2:E" & lastR).Value2 = arr
End Sub

Function TotalHoursPerDaysGroup(val As String, curDay As Date, workingH As Double) As Double
    Dim curMonth As Long, startDN As String, endDN As String, nb_days As Long
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, dayN As String, d As Date, arrND, boolCount As Boolean
    
    'Dim arrDaysRo: arrDaysRo = Split("lun.,mar.,mie.,joi,vin.,sâm.,dum.", ",") 'localized days name...
    'Dim arrDaysEn: arrDaysEn = Split("Mon,Tue,Wen,Thu,Fry,Sat,Sun", ",")
    
    curMonth = Month(curDay) ' current month
    dtStart = DateSerial(Year(curDay), curMonth, 1)
    dtEnd = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(dtStart, 0)
    
    arrND = Split(val, " ")
    startDN = left(arrND(1), 3)
    endDN = left(arrND(3), 3)
    
    For d = dtStart To dtEnd
        dayN = Format(d, "ddd")
        If dayN = startDN Then boolCount = True
        'If arrDaysEn(Application.match(dayN, arrDaysRo, 0) - 1) = startDN Then boolCount = True
        If boolCount Then
            nb_days = nb_days + 1
        End If
        If d = endDN Then boolCount = False
        'If arrDaysEn(Application.match(dayN, arrDaysRo, 0) - 1) = endDN Then boolCount = False
    Next d
    
    TotalHoursPerDaysGroup = nb_days * workingH
End Function
```

I tried using first three characters of the days name, but because of localization, I couldn't, so I created two equivalence arrays to overpass the problem. I let them in the function, just in case...

If no such a problem, you can comment the lines making the equivalence and uncomment the ones above them. I can see that my solution used in the function is very similar with the one already posted...

Comment: sorry but your code was complicated when I used it.

Comment: @James Franco What complicated should mean? You should only copy the code I posted and run `getHours`. Please, copy the updated function code. I thought that you understand what is to be adapted in case of not regionalized days name and I configured as for using such standard days name. Then, **if your data range in the sheet starts from column "B:B" to "D:D", in the first column being the string containing "every 'day name' to 'day name' pattern and in "D:D" 'Working hours'**. It will return the total month hours in "E:E". `curDate` should contain a **date from the month to be processed**.

Comment: @James Franco If the date containing the month to be  processed is in a text box, combo, list box you should use `curDate = MyTextbox.Text`...

Comment: I have Start button in my main sheet and I used module that compute all the days. So, how can I call the sub inside of the module where I used As String of my textbox?